# Getting different output for using weekofyear vs date_format in SPARK SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use SPARK SQL for doing some aggregations on a data on CSV format.
I am having confusion between weekofyear(timestamp_col) vs date_format(timestamp_col,'w').
I am getting different results for both, can any one explain the difference ?

Here is the DATA : https://controlc.com/5f4eee31

I am using these code to use this :

```
    spark.read.option("inferSchema",true).option("header",true).csv("data/data.csv").createOrReplaceTempView("traffic")

  spark.sql(
    """
      | SELECT
      | MIN(DATE(page_view_ts)) as start_date,
      | COUNT(r_session_id) / COUNT(l_session_id) AS bounced_sessions,
      | COUNT(CASE WHEN lander_page = '/home' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS home_sessions,
      | COUNT(CASE WHEN lander_page = '/lander-1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS lander_sessions
      | FROM traffic
      | GROUP BY date_format(page_view_ts,'w')
      | ORDER BY start_date
      |""".stripMargin).show(100,false)

  spark.sql(
    """
      | SELECT
      | MIN(DATE(page_view_ts)) as start_date,
      | COUNT(r_session_id) / COUNT(l_session_id) AS bounced_sessions,
      | COUNT(CASE WHEN lander_page = '/home' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS home_sessions,
      | COUNT(CASE WHEN lander_page = '/lander-1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS lander_sessions
      | FROM traffic
      | GROUP BY weekofyear(page_view_ts)
      | ORDER BY start_date
      |""".stripMargin).show(100,false)
```

Here is the difference in output respectively,

```
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
|start_date|bounced_sessions  |home_sessions|lander_sessions|
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
|2012-06-01|0.6057142857142858|175          |0              |
|2012-06-03|0.5871212121212122|792          |0              |
|2012-06-10|0.616             |875          |0              |
|2012-06-17|0.5581947743467933|492          |350            |
|2012-06-24|0.5827814569536424|369          |386            |
|2012-07-01|0.5820512820512821|392          |388            |
|2012-07-08|0.5667915106117354|390          |411            |
|2012-07-15|0.5423529411764706|429          |421            |
|2012-07-22|0.5138190954773869|402          |394            |
|2012-07-29|0.4970817120622568|33           |995            |
|2012-08-05|0.5381784728610856|0            |1087           |
|2012-08-12|0.5140280561122245|0            |998            |
|2012-08-19|0.5009881422924901|0            |1012           |
|2012-08-26|0.5378151260504201|0            |833            |
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
|start_date|bounced_sessions  |home_sessions|lander_sessions|
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
|2012-06-01|0.6079295154185022|227          |0              |
|2012-06-04|0.5892634207240949|801          |0              |
|2012-06-11|0.6116173120728929|878          |0              |
|2012-06-18|0.56590084643289  |455          |372            |
|2012-06-25|0.5714285714285714|376          |401            |
|2012-07-02|0.5846153846153846|396          |384            |
|2012-07-09|0.5662949194547707|394          |413            |
|2012-07-16|0.5314769975786925|415          |411            |
|2012-07-23|0.5216852540272615|407          |400            |
|2012-07-30|0.5019120458891013|0            |1046           |
|2012-08-06|0.5276243093922652|0            |1086           |
|2012-08-13|0.5151515151515151|0            |990            |
|2012-08-20|0.5048543689320388|0            |1030           |
|2012-08-27|0.5417789757412399|0            |742            |
+----------+------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: date_format `'w'` is deprecated and no longer supported as of Spark 3. I believe weekofyear is giving the correct result.

Comment: When using date_format with 'w'  , the MySQL's result matches with it,but not with weekofyear. @mck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two functions return two different results for the same input, but both results are right.
e.g.

```
weekofyear(2021-01-01)  returns 53
date_format(2021-01-01, w) returns 1
```

So 2021-01-01 is still 53rd week of 2020 but at the same time the 1st week of 2021. And local maters too, cause it depends on dayofweek when week starts. I'd prefer to use always the same function.
You can see some details about the first week of year in [ISO-8601 week dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)